# Does port triggering from port 80 to port 80 make sense?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

In troubleshooting a VoIP quality issue, tech support had me set up numerous port triggering ranges. One of the ranges was:

- Triggered Range: 80 to 80
- Forwarded Range: 80 to 80

Based on my probably-flawed understanding of port triggering, this means when a client on my network issues an outgoing request through port 80 (e.g. to a web server over http), then until that instance of port 80 triggering times out, that client essentially "owns" port 80—responses go back to that client.

It seems this would cause problems if two people were browsing at once, since you'd want responses routed via NAT to the requester, not to whichever client currently "owns" the 80 channel. And since I enabled these rules, I've had a couple of mysterious problems where no web pages would load for several seconds.

I suspect I'm misunderstanding something. What is it?

Comment: Huh? VoIP does not even use port 80. Clueless Tech Support. VoIP normally uses 5060/5061 for SIP signalling and another range for RTP

Comment: Only reason I can think of to do this is to make sure port 80 is stalled to work out if http traffic is causing issues, but yeah, its unlikely and more likely to be a clueless tech support.

Comment: Take port 80 off the list.  Tech support was throwing ideas out there to see if any of them stick.  Clearly they are not very knowledgeable.

Comment: @DavidPostill If you post an answer along these lines I'll accept. When I pressed the tech about why he included 80/443 his explanation was unclear, but I think he meant that those ports are used as part of some handshake to establish the connection. So this might make sense if I were unable to make a call at all, but I couldn't see the sense in doing it to address voice lag. I've since removed those ports and our browsers are no longer seizing up.

Comment: @AndyGiesler Answer added (I've thrown in a little extra information, I used to provide tech support for a VoIP provider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In troubleshooting a VoIP quality issue, tech support had me set up numerous port triggering ranges.

```
Triggered Range: 80 to 80
Forwarded Range: 80 to 80
```

This is strange (and a probably an indication of poor technical support):

- VoIP does not use port 80.
- VoIP normally uses 5060/5061 for SIP signalling and another range for RTP
- The exact port numbers used are dependent on your VoIP provider.

---

#### I couldn't see the sense in doing it to address voice lag

You are correct. There are many things that can cause "voice lag" on VoIP calls but further troubleshooting is not possible with the information provided in the question.

I would start by looking at the quality of the internet connection:

- VoIP quality is affected by things like Jitter, RTT, and Latency, which need specialised testing of the connection.
- VoIP providers normally have specialised test servers to measure these.